# Download and play a single game on PS4

Tags: ps4

Okay, so when I was in Australia I tried to buy Tekken 7, but couldn't for some reason so I bought it on my cousins account. I was wondering if there was a way for him to let me download Tekken onto my Ps4 and for him to still be able to play his games while I'm playing Tekken. Help !!!

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work, your cousin's account has to stay on your PS4, and also be assigned as your PS4's primary account.

Only the primary account can share digital content across other accounts on the same system.